# When expectation of minimizer is minimizer of expectation?

Tags: optimization, expected-value, unbiased-estimator, mathematical-statistics

$X$ is a random variable with unknown distribution law $P$ taking values in set $A$.

Given $\rho : I \times A \to \mathbb{R}_+$, where $I$ is a closed bounded real interval, it is clear that

$$  \mathbb{E} \min_{t \in I} \rho(t,X) \le \min_{t \in I}  \mathbb{E} \rho(t,X)  $$

Now concern estimate
   $$
     \hat r = \arg \, \min_{t \in I} \rho(t,X)
   $$
and value
   $$ 
      r =  \arg \, \min_{t \in I} \mathbb{E} \rho(t,X) 
   $$

The problem is to find condition on $\rho$ which makes $\hat r$ an unbiased estimator of $r$, i. e.

$$ \mathbb{E} \hat r = r $$

Are where any known results for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume the argmin always exists and is unique. Since our condition needs to work for any possible distribution of $X$ we need the argmin to be linear in $X$ for the result to hold (If the argmin were a non-linear function of $X$ then some part of it would be locally strictly concave or convex, and if the distribution of $X$ had support in a subset of this region then by Jensen's inequality $E\hat{r}\neq r$). A sufficient condition for this is for $\rho$ to be of the form $\rho((a+bX)t)$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.